# Image Preload not working when loaded from a controller

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a photo gallery.  It works just fine, however, the images are not preloading properly. I am running an asp.net 4 c# mvc3 server with razor tags.  I have read a couple different ideas about why this happens but am unable to solve this myself at present.
Here is how the image is built:

```
<img src="/ActionLibrary/GetPhoto/53" onmouseover="display(this);" />
<img src="/ActionLibrary/GetPhoto/55" id="picTarget">
```

Here is how it is called to display:

```
function display(imgObject){
  document.getElementById("picTarget").src = imgObject.src;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
        // GET: /Browse/GetPhoto/id
    public ActionResult GetPhoto(int id)
    {

    }
```

The picture shows up fine, and is rendered - however, the only issue is that it reloads each time.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  I am unsure why the image keeps getting reloaded.  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are requesting that images get cached in the browser.

Comment: epig: can you please post your comment as an answer - you solved my question and I would love to give you some credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As epignosisx points out, the images were not requested to be cached, so they were not and in turn every reference caused a server request.  The fix was rather simple...

```
// GET: /Browse/GetPhoto/id
[OutputCache(Duration=600)]
public ActionResult GetPhoto(int id)
{
...
```

This will cause the photo to stay in the client side cache for 10 minutes (600s = 10m).